# Set ArrayFormula to many Excel cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I have an array formula that outputs a single value, and I want to give a whole bunch of cells this same array formula. The problem is when I assign the array formula to the range, it interprets the formula in such a way as them all sharing the output of a single call to the array formula, rather than each of them outputting a separate value.

To show you what I mean, I'm using the following code:

```
With MarginalData
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(13, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).FormulaArray = pullFormula
End With
```

**What I want**, is a result that looks like this:
[image: desired result]

That is what it looks like when I enter the array formula separately in every cell in the range.

But **what I get** is this:
[image: given result]

The output of the array formula in the first cell is repeated in all the columns - they all share the same output.

How can I programatically assign the array formula as though each cell had it assigned separately?

---

The formula is:

> {=INDEX(BatchResults,MATCH(TTID&CHAR(1)&ROW()-1,BatchResultsTTIDS&CHAR(1)&BatchResultsLayers,0),MATCH(A$1,BatchTTIDData!$1:$1,0))}

It must be put in as an array formula because it performs a match not on a single column, but on two concatenated columns. The concatenation of the columns must be returned as an array, hence the formula must be entered as an array formula.

---

The simplest solution so far, a variant of the accepted answer below, is the following:

```
Const pullFormula = "=INDEX(BatchResults,MATCH(TTID&CHAR(1)&ROW()-1,BatchResultsTTIDS&CHAR(1)&BatchResultsLayers,0),MATCH(A$1,BatchTTIDData!$1:$1,0))"
With wrksht
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(13, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        .Formula = pullFormula
        .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
    End With
End With
```

Comment: You need to be able to make 'pullFormula' dependent on the cell it's in, but we need the string for that to show you how to make that happen (if it's possible).

Comment: As you can see above, pullFormula is already dependent on the cell it's in. It takes into account the current row, and the column header (`A$1`), which is different for each column.

Comment: Good question. And as per [this article](http://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/) you have the best approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or pick up the Array Formula as R1C1, assign to the range as FormulaR1C1, then assign the FormulaR1C1 as Array Formula. This assumes Array Formula is in cell A2

```
Sub test()

With Sheet1
    pullFormula = .Range("A2").FormulaR1C1
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(13, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))

    Rng.Formula = pullFormula
    Rng.FormulaArray = Rng.FormulaR1C1

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution works, but the strangest thing happens, when setting the formula array equal to the formular1c1, the operation is incredibly slow - even slower than looping all the cells manually, which is what it appears to be doing if you execute the line of code with screen updating turned on.

Comment: @Alain Ouch that is quite slow over large ranges! Perhaps it would be quicker to use my method for the first row only then autofill down EG Rng.AutoFill Destination:=Rng.Resize(999, Rng.Columns.Count), Type:=xlFillDefault. Or using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` is a bit faster

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it semi-automatically. Set formula for the first row, then use FillDown.

```
Private Sub soCopyFormula()

    Dim MarginalData As Worksheet
    Set MarginalData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    With MarginalData
        Set oRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(13, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        ' for each column
        For i = 0 To oRange.Columns.Count - 1
            ' set first row
            oRange(1, i).FormulaArray = pullFormula
            ' copy down
            oRange.Columns(i).FillDown
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution works but it's more convoluted than I want. My temporary solution was actually slightly simpler than this, consisting of setting the formula to one cell, copying across, and then copying down.

Comment: @Alain Yes, definitely a workaround. I've not really used FormulaR1C1, but I will remember that now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of A$1, try

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))
```

Comment: I don't know why this was upvoted so much, COL() isn't even a valid function in excel - the function you meant was COLUMN(). Furthermore, ADDRESS returns a string "$A$1", "$B$1", etc. The MATCH function takes a range, not a string. Placing that in the function breaks it.

Comment: That's not all that's wrong with it, to make this function work after you've converted the reference into a string, one is forced to use the INDIRECT function, which is volatile and means these expensive array formulas will be recalculated every time anything is changed in the workbook, which is horribly unacceptable.

Comment: And even if someone put up with the INDIRECT formula, your change STILL accomplishes nothing, the whole range is still treated as having a single output, and the same repeating problem occurs rather than each cell getting its own value.

Comment: I'm less disappointed in your answer and more disappointed in the fact that 3 people mindlessly supported an answer that clearly wasn't correct. We all make mistakes but people shouldn't be voting if they aren't verifying the answers.

Comment: @Alain, I didn't give it as a correct answer, notice the word __try__.  It was an attempt, that only you could test, to help you find the answer.  Sometimes a clue is all I need when I'm hunting for the answer.