# Calculate percentage and populate result in another Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need help creating a macro/vba to query from an excel database called "database" to match multiple criteria in "Results" and calculate a percentage and populate in a column.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByCB_rXHlkEba05RU3p5RGlnM1U/edit?pli=1

**Worksheet - "Database"**

```
Fields:
YEAR 
Region# 
Region_Name 
Store#  
Store_NAME  
ITM-GRADE   
Whse    
Item#   
Item_Desc   
Type    
Group   
Qty
```

**Worksheeet = "Results"**

```
Criteria        Year      2005      2005      2005   2005
Criteria        ITM-GRADE GradeA1   GradeA1   GradeA1    GradeA1
Criteria        Whse      Whse2     Whse2     Whse2  Whse2
Criteria        Group     11 to 44  11        55 to 66   55 to 66
Criteria        Type      Q1        Q2        Q1     Q2

Region# Store#  percentage          
1001    1001-002    Group 11-44 divided by Group 11-66          
1001    1001-003    %   %   %   %
1001    1001-004    %   %   %   %
1003    1003-001    %   %   %   %
1003    1003-002    %   %   %   %
1003    1003-003    %   %   %   %
1005    1005-001    %   %   %   %
```

vba to match Region#, Store#, Year, ITM-Grade, Whse, Group, Type with "Database" take Group 11-44 divided by Group 11-66 and populate the percentage in each column.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can upload a file to Google Docs or Dropbox, but this sort of very specific question which you can't even adequately describe, and which demonstrates no attempt at solving the problem on your own, is not likely to get many helpful responses.

Comment: Thanks David.  This is my first time posting and new to this environment.  I will do my possible best to attach the file which shows the database, the result worksheet and how I do it manually. It's a lot easier visually.

Comment: I learnt quite a bit today, opened a Gmail account and sharing this link, hopefully it works.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByCB_rXHlkEbS3U1SDFzRkRCd00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Brian - All of your formula are giving `#Div/0` errors, it's impossible to try and figure out what you're actually trying to do. If you can revise the formulas so that they don't error, it might be possible for someone to help you. Otherwise, people here are happy to troubleshoot your code, but it's generally frowned upon to ask "Please write my code for me" type of questions.

Comment: Thanks David.  I had to make some changes to the database contents.  My formula was not working with codes with text so I changes them to numbers and it works.  Please see the attached file:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByCB_rXHlkEba05RU3p5RGlnM1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK it makes a little more sense now. I do not think an array formula is needed for this. Also, I think you are missing `Database!$J$2:$J$8043=E$5` in the denominator of cell E8.

Comment: See revision to my answer below. Definitely much easier to just automate the use of `AutoFilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have valid formula, with a tiny bit of tinkering this solution would work for you:

[Set ArrayFormula to many Excel cells using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048076/set-arrayformula-to-many-excel-cells-using-vba)

However, your formula exceed 255 characters, which will cause a 1004 error.

You may be able to shrink this formula considerably using Named Ranges.

**UPDATE**

Rather than using nasty array formulas, IMO it is probably better and easier to automate the use of `AutoFilter` method on your database range, and then use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` in the `QTY` column to calculate the numerator & denominator of the equation, compute the score in memory, and then write to the worksheet cells.

This method appears to return the same results as your array formula, and also allows for multiple "Group" criteria, which your formulas did not allow for.

[image: Screenshot of results]

[**Using the updated file**](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByCB_rXHlkEba05RU3p5RGlnM1U/edit?usp=sharing), insert a normal code module and paste the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UsingAutoFilters()

Dim wsDB As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
Dim rngResults As Range, dbRange As Range
Dim sYear$, sRegion$, sStore$, sItmGrade$, sItem$, sWhse$, sType$, sGroup$
Dim r As Long, c As Long 'row & column iterator
Dim myDenominator, myNumerator As Double 'used for calculations

Set wsDB = Worksheets("Database")
'## This is the database table ##'
Set dbRange = wsDB.Range("A1:L8043")

Set wsResults = Worksheets("QueryResult")
'## This is the range of data in the QueryResults table, E8 to the end of the data ##'
Set rngResults = wsResults.Range("E8:H13") '## Modify as needed'

    '## Iterate over columns in the results table'
    For c = 1 To rngResults.Columns.Count
        'Capture the filter values for each COLUMN.'
        With wsResults
            sYear = .Cells(1, c + 4).Value
            sItmGrade = .Cells(2, c + 4).Value
            sWhse = .Cells(3, c + 4).Value
            sItem = .Cells(4, c + 4).Value
            sType = .Cells(5, c + 4).Value
            sGroup = .Cells(6, c + 4).Value
        End With

    '## Set the filters ##'
        'Filter the year
        dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sYear
        'Filter the itemgrade'
        dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=sItmGrade
        'Filter the whse'
        dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=sWhse
        'Filter the Item#'
        dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=sItem

    '## Now, for each row in the table...'
        For r = 1 To rngResults.Rows.Count
            'Capture the row filter values for each ROW.'
            sRegion = wsResults.Cells(r + 7, 1).Value
            sStore = wsResults.Cells(r + 7, 3).Value

        '## Apply the row filters ##'
            'Filter the region'
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sRegion
            'filter the store #'
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=sStore

        '## Calculate the denominator ##'
            'SUM OF VISIBLE CELLS IN wsDB.Column L
            myDenominator = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
                            dbRange.Columns(12).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

        '## Now, filter for the type & group, to get the Numerator'
            'Filter the type'
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=sType
            'Filter the group(s) criteria
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array(Split(sGroup, ",")), _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues

        '## Calculate the numerator ##'
            myNumerator = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
                            dbRange.Columns(12).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

            If myDenominator = 0 Then
                'Avoid Div/0 errors:'
                rngResults(r, c).Value = "N/A"
            Else:
                '## get the result and place it in the cell ##'
                rngResults(r, c).Value = myNumerator / myDenominator
            End If
            'turn off the autofilter on fields 10 & 11'
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=10
            dbRange.AutoFilter Field:=11
         Next r

        'turn off the autofilter'
        wsDB.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next c
End Sub
```

**Note** If you have multiple "Group" criteria (e.g., you want to do Groups 11 thru 33), use a comma-separated list in that cell, i.e., `11, 22, 33`.  The "Group" criteria is the only field that can accept multiple criteria.

[image: Group Criteria]

**Note** You will need to update the criteria fields in columns G & H, since these are not valid in the updated XLSM file.

[image: Criteria fields need updating]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.  It's a learning curve for me.  Much appreciated.

Comment: OK. First I came up with a way that works for a single criteria, then I think I have another way that works for multiple criteria. I tried two different methods and both yield the same results. It is pretty gnarly, though. I can post something tomorrow or just send you an updated XLSM file over Google, if you're interested.

Comment: Another, easier method would be to use Autofilter. This can be automated a hell of a lot more easily than these array formulas, which I did basically for my own knowledge/learning. I'll try to put that together, too.

Comment: Amazing.  Nice, it works perfectly.  Thanks very much David.  I will follow how you did it to populate more columns if I decided to add more columns.  Very much appreciated.  You wouldn't imagine how easy you made my work.

Comment: No problem. I tried it with the array formula and it works that way, but is considerably slower, and more difficult to implement. In any case, I'm glad it's working. Please consider marking this as the "accepted" answer, if it's been helpful.

Comment: Could you please help me with calculating a Group say 33 to 44 and another 55 to 66 (with the same criteria used for other column).  That would solve everything that I need.  Thanks again.

Comment: just put `33, 44` in the cell for Group Criteria (row 6), and in the next Group Criteria cell put `55, 66`

Comment: You're welcome.  A final, friendly reminder to please mark this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: How do I answer as Accepted.  I don't this option anywhere, can you help.  I'm sorry this is new to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you David.  You are awesome in my book.